# Trying to "revive" Snip Insights - API call fails

Tags: azure, azure-functions, endpoint, failover

This is my first entry so please have mercy.

I am currently trying to use the old but still (somewhat) working "SnipInsights" (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ai/ai-lab-snip-insights and https://github.com/Microsoft/Snip-Insights).
However no matter which API key I put into the different options and no matter which endpoint I chose (default or the ones azure portal is suggesting) - I only get text / OCR recognition to work.

Anyone has any idea which endpoints to use or which API key I should create or if its no longer possible to use the app at all?

Seems the first entity search doesn't work in code as I get

> System.NullReferenceExceptionHResult=0x80004003Nachricht = Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.Quelle = SnipStapelüberwachung:bei SnipInsight.AIServices.AIViewModels.ImageAnalysisViewModel.d__33.MoveNext() in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Snip-Insights6\SnipInsight\AIServices\AIViewModels\ImageAnalysisViewModel.cs: Zeile178

```
try
{
    foreach (ImageAnalysisModel.Category category in model.Categories)
    {
        foreach (ImageAnalysisModel.Celebrity celebrity in category.Detail.Celebrities)
        {
            var celebrityModel = await entityHandler.GetResult(celebrity.Name);

            if (celebrityModel.Entities != null)
            {
                var entry = celebrityModel.Entities.List.FirstOrDefault();

                if (entry != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    var celebModel = new CelebrityModel
                    {
                        Name = entry.Name,
                        Image = entry.Image.URL,
                        URL = entry.URL,
                        Description = entry.Description
                    };

                    var result = await newsHandler.GetResult(celebrity.Name);

                    celebModel.News = new ObservableCollection<NewsModel>(result.News);

                    foreach(NewsModel newsModel in celebModel.News)
                    {
                        newsModel.DatePublished = newsModel.DatePublished.Substring(0, 10);
                        newsModel.Description = newsModel.Description.Substring(0, 150) + "...";
                    }

                    rect.Tag = celebModel;

                    rect.Width = celebrity.FaceRectangle.Width;
                    rect.Height = celebrity.FaceRectangle.Height;
                    rect.Stroke = Brushes.Transparent;
                    rect.StrokeThickness = 2;
                    rect.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                    rect.ToolTip = entry.Name;
                    rect.MouseDown += CelebritySelected;
                    rect.MouseEnter += ShowCelebrityRectangle;
                    rect.MouseLeave += HideCelebrityRectangle;

                    celebrities.Children.Add(rect);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, celebrity.FaceRectangle.Left);
                    Canvas.SetTop(rect, celebrity.FaceRectangle.Top);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Resources.Exception_at_celebrities + e.Message);
}
```

while using the following API endpoints

[image]

Anyone knows maybe which services to create in azure and how to get especially the entity search key, image analysis key and the LUIS AppID / CLU AppID/Key?

I tried the hyperlinks which led me to different services on Azure which I created but it seems still only text recognition does work.